# Google Cast Sender App via Vb.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, chromecast, google-cast

i am currently developing an application written in Vb.Net. Is there any chance to tell all Chromecasts in the same network of the application to start a specific application ?

I´ve searched the whole internet since months, and there is no SDK i can find for .Net. Anyone knows how to do this, or can point me to the right direction ?

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such implementation in .NET, but you can look into protocol implementations in Node.js ([V1](https://github.com/wearefractal/nodecast) [V2](https://github.com/vincentbernat/nodecastor)) and in java ([V1](https://github.com/entertailion/Caster) [V2](https://github.com/vitalidze/chromecast-java-api-v2)). I am implementing V2 in java. You should also take into account that V1 is retiring, and soon they will move to V2 for all applications.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I will look onto it, and eventually we will translate it to .Net and provide an open source project.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no .Net sdk. Moreover, you need to be connected to each chromecast device individually to be able to communicate with them, hence no "broadcast" messaging.

Comment: That there is no official .Net SDK is totally clear to me. I thought anyone got the same problem earlier, and wrote an inofficial SDK hinmself. Anyway, how do apps talk to ChromeCasts ?

Comment: Communication is over a secure proprietary channel.

Comment: So there is no chance to speak to the Chromecast via .Net ?

Comment: There is no official way to do that.

Comment: I am not asking for an official way to do this. I am asking for any way to do this :) course if there is no official way to do this I had to do this in an unofficial way.

Answer (score 0):

.Net development is possible using [Sharpcaster](https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster).

Also look at [GoogleCast](https://github.com/kakone/GoogleCast).